# How to prevent content disappearing behind fixed header?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, header, fixed

I have a fixed header which is overlapping the content below.

I have tried adding padding-top/margin-top to the body, page-wrapper, and about section, but no luck. I am using an inner flex box div inside the header, and I have a hidden sidebar which has 100% height when active. I have a home page with a hero image that has a height of 100vh and a padding-top of 9rem which seems to work, however I don't intend to use a hero image on this particular page.

HTML:

```html
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper content">

<!-- HEADER -->
<header id="header">
  <div class="header-inner">
    <div class="header-col header-col-1">
      <div class="menu-trigger">
        <span class="menu-trigger-icon">
          <span class="menu-trigger-bar menu-trigger-bar-top"></span>
          <span class="menu-trigger-bar menu-trigger-bar-middle"></span>
          <span class="menu-trigger-bar menu-trigger-bar-bottom"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="menu-trigger-title">Menu</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-col header-col-2">
      <a class="logo" href="../index.html">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-col header-col-3">
      <a class="click-to-call" href="tel:+44-1492-877-832">
        <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn-book-now" href="">Book Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- END / HEADER -->

<!-- SIDE NAV -->
<nav class="side-nav">
  <div class="side-nav-inner">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Book Now</a>
      </li>
    </ul>      
    <ul class="social-media">
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- END / SIDE NAV -->

<main id="main">

  <section class="about">
    <div class="about-inner">
      <h1>About Us</h1>
      <span class="hr"></span>
```

CSS:

```css
#header {
  background: #fdd400;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 .2rem .9rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 .2rem .9rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 .2rem .9rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.header-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 0 6%;
}

#main {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.about {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.about-inner {
  align-items: center;
  color: #2c2a29;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 6%;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  text-align: center;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `padding-top` on `#main` should work, among other things, unless other CSS somewhere is interfering, or you can't predict the height of the header.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your project in a code sandbox based on what you pasted, to get an idea of what the problem is. There's some styles missing I think, but it seems at least what you are trying to achieve can be done by wrapping the main and sidebar divs in a content div, and then displace that downwards. Like so:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9rem;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

There are other ways to this as well, like padding the content downwards, but that can create some side effects as well.

You can have a look here:

https://03jknqq7kw.codesandbox.io/